# SQL 2012 Server Management Studio setup process halts for no obvious reason

Tags: sql-server

I have had great pleasure from designing databases in the Transact-SQL language, under the SQL 2008 and 2012 Server Management Studio.

Since I installed Windows 10, I have been unable to install the SQL Server Management Studio, in both the 2012 and 2014 versions. Unfortunately, the 2008 version is not compatible with Windows 10.

During the setup process, it seems to halt for no apparent reason. There are no error messages or other apparent failures, it just seems to stop. The harddrive LED and the DVD drive LED, from which I run the install process, indicates little or no activity, for a very long time.

The processes at which the setup seems to stop, appear to be about writing og generating something called 'native images', and are as follows:

Install_sql_common_core_Cpu64_Action : Write_NativeImage_64. : Generating native images

and during another attempt :

Install_SqlSupport_Cpu64_Action: Write_NativeImage

Does anyone know what writing native images is all about ?

Can anyone help or give me an advice as what to do or try ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you check event viewer and/or installation log files?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. No, I didn't check any of those. Can you tell me how and what to look for ?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue that you mentioned, using Windows 10. Besides this, I also tested the SQL Server 2016 and the problem persisted.

I found a similar problem with 2008 version, reported on this link (https://support.avg.com/answers?id=906b00000008nRnAAI), and it was an antivirus issue. It may be the real issue in our case, but I don't have any technical details about it.

In the end, I managed to install SQL Server 2016 CTP management tools first, and after it, I installed the server tools. For that, I turned off AVG 2015 and Windows Defender. Moreover, I set my "Windows Update Settings" -> "For developers" -> to Developer mode. Thus, this problem can be related to the order of installation, antivirus, settings, or something else ...

Answer (score 1):

According to the Microsoft SQL Server Forum, the problem is caused by a feature by the name of ngen.exe, Native Image Generator, a part of the Microsoft .NET Framework 4.6 and 4.5.

Ngen.exe causes the SQL Server setup installation process to halt, until shut down. Unfortunately it restarts itself frequently, a problem I still haven´t discovered any solution for.

Thanks to everyone who read about this problem and to Paolo who gave his reply.

Comment: I had the same problem upgrading to Sql 2016. Both the AVG and Defender options did not work but killing the Ngen.exe did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. In my case I use windows 10 professional edition, disabling AVG did not work for me so I totally uninstall AVG and run the setup file under administrator's right then It is install successfully.